# Make sure that message has been sent

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

Let's say you are sending a message through your bot to all servers.

If you do too many actions through the api at the same time, some actions will fail silently.
Is there any way to prevent this? Or can you make sure, that a message really has been sent?

```
for tmpChannel in tmpAllChannels:
        channel = bot.get_channel(tmpChannel)
        if(not channel == None):
            try:
                if(pText == None):
                    await channel.send(embed= pEmbed)
                else:
                    await channel.send(pText, embed= pEmbed)
            except Exception as e:
                ExceptionHandler.handle(e)
```

Comment: No, that's simply API abuse, you can get banned for that. Simply put some delay between the iterations with `asyncio.sleep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
for tmpChannel in tmpAllChannels:
        channel = bot.get_channel(tmpChannel)
        if(not channel == None):
            try:
                if(pText == None):
                    await channel.send(embed= pEmbed)
                else:
                    await channel.send(pText, embed= pEmbed)
            except Exception as e:
                ExceptionHandler.handle(e)
            finally:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)  # this will sleep the bot for 1 second
```

Never hammer the API without any delay between them. `asyncio.sleep` will put a delay between messages, and you will send all of them without failing.